# CodeIgniter Session Expire in Config file

Tags: codeigniter, session

I am working on CodeIgniter framework.

What I want, is to set the session expiring time of the site to 3 hours ie, (3600*3=10800 seconds).

But when I set the `$config['sess_expiration'] = 10800;` in **config.php**, the session is getting expired within around 30 minutes of idle and is redirected to login page.

Why is this happening?

These are some of my session settings in config

```
  $config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
   $config['sess_expiration']      = 10800;
      $config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
  $config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
  $config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
  $config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
  $config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
  $config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: Thanks Colin for editing question properly.

Comment: Is anyone interested in this topic?

Comment: are you using database for session?

Comment: i tried with setting "session expire on close" to TRUE and gave $config['sess_expiration']        = 10; and itwas then working for 10 seconds, but if i give 10800 seconds itgetsexpired within 30 minutes

Comment: @tpae $config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;

Comment: Can you post up more variables? all the sess_ ones.

Comment: you have the database for ci_sessions too?

Comment: What might be the issue here?

Comment: I made some adjustments to my answer. please check it. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have the ci_sessions table in your database.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

**EDIT:** also, make sure you are not using **$_SESSION** versus **$this->session->set_userdata($array);**

**Link:** http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: I will check that ,Thanks, but currently I cannot check db ,i will check it within 2 hours, Also could that be the only problem occuring

Comment: If you are using the latest CodeIgniter, and that's your configuration, then yes. I don't see any other problems. If you are not sure about having ci_sessions table, that's probably the issue. If not, try disabling use database feature, and try it out with cookies.

Comment: CodeIgniter doesn't really come with installation, but deep inside the manuals, they talk about ci_sessions table here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: how that could be done with cookies,can it be written in config file and checked?  @tpae

Comment: if you set sess_use_database to FALSE it will fallback to cookies

Comment: also @tpae , if i set sess_use_database to FALSE will it work if i dont have a table ci_sessions

Comment: yes it should work. It will set cookie expiration time to the time you set for session to expire.

Comment: Ok thank you tpae, i will check it within2 hours and come back,nowI am not in a situation to check it.

Comment: but I did not set anywhere to expire session within around 30 minutes, thenhow it was gettingexpired at thattime.

Comment: could you help me to try with cookies,

Answer (score 1):

Check the code like this:

```
if($login)
{
   $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = TRUE;
}
else
{
   $this->session->sess_expiration = 60*60*3;
   $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = FALSE;
}

  $this->session->set_userdata('your_item');
```

Comment: Would be in which controller file?

Comment: Should I provide this in all of the COntroller files?  @Valeh

Comment: in that controller where you set session data :) so, it depends on your code. BTW, it's just logic of the process. you must write your values instead of $login and 'your_item'.

Comment: there is alogin checking function inside one of the controller, so i should be using the above code inside it right?

Comment: then what about the value of session expire variables in config page?

Answer (score 1):

Check your configuration of `session.gc_lifetime` in `php.ini`.

By default, this is 1440, or 24 minutes. This means that whenever PHP's garbage-collector runs (it does this with a configured probability on every pageload), any sessions older than 24 minutes will be cleared out via the `gc()` function in your CodeIgniter session driver.