# Codeigniter session logs out automatically in few days

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

Codeigniter session logs out automatically in few days. my config.php values:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files'
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 100000000;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

CodeIgniter Version = 3.1.11

PHP Version = 7.4.20

Comment: Maybe a duplicated of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804103/codeigniter-session-expire-in-config-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CodeIgniter Session Expire in Config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804103/codeigniter-session-expire-in-config-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_samesite'] = 'Lax';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 72800;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH.'sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 72800;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```